# How to create a polygon with jcsg

Tags: java, cad

I'm using JCSG with the following code to make a polygon.  I'm expecting it to look like the attached image but the result is a single triangle.

[image]

```
List<Vertex> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    Vector3d normal = Vector3d.xyz(0, 0, 0);
    vertices.add(new Vertex(Vector3d.xyz(0, 0, 0), normal));
    vertices.add(new Vertex(Vector3d.xyz(100, 0, 0), normal));
    vertices.add(new Vertex(Vector3d.xyz(0, 100, 0), normal));
    vertices.add(new Vertex(Vector3d.xyz(50, 25, 0), normal));
        Polygon p = new Polygon(vertices);
    List<Polygon> t = p.toTriangles();
    CSG csg = CSG.fromPolygons(t.get(0));
```

I've tries many variations on the code but I always get the same result.
I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Standard constructor uses three of your points, try this one, and let me know if it worked:

```
List<Vector3d> vertices = new ArrayList<>();

vertices.add(Vector3d.xyz(0, 0, 0));
vertices.add(Vector3d.xyz(50, 25, 0));
vertices.add(Vector3d.xyz(100, 0, 0));
vertices.add(Vector3d.xyz(0, 100, 0));

List<Polygon> t = Polygon.fromConcavePoints(vertices);
CSG csg = CSG.fromPolygons(t);
```

Comment: Edited last line to use whole list instead of first element.

Comment: Thanks.  fromConcavePoints takes a list of Vector3d instead of Vertex so normal is not required. But that does the trick.

Comment: Glad I could help :D